# Generate lists from a list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I've been searching around and I couldnt find a smart way of doing a split of a list.

Let's say we have the following example:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String gender;

    public Person(String name, int age, String gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    // Getters/setters
}
```

So then I have:

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
personList.add(new Person("Adam", 30, "male"));
personList.add(new Person("John", 32, "male"));
personList.add(new Person("Monica", 30, "female"));
personList.add(new Person("Sophia", 20, "female"));
personList.add(new Person("Carol", 25, "female"));
```

Is there a way that I could generate two new lists of Person using Stream API grouping male and female?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the brevity, but I'm on the train going home.

```
Map<String, List<Person>> map = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender));
```

And the code

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String genre;
 
    public Person(String name, int age, String genre) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    // getters and setters
}

public class GroupBy {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Person> list = ArrayList();

        list.add(new Person("Adam", 30, male));
        list.add(new Person("John", 32, male));
        list.add(new Person("Monica", 30, female));
        list.add(new Person("Sophia", 20, female));
        list.add(new Person("Carol", 25, female));

        Map<String, List<Person>> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I were you, I'd stream the `List` and use `Collectors.partitioningBy` to collect it to a `Map<Boolean, List<Person>>` where the males are `true` (or `false`), and the females are the opposite of the males.  It's as simple as the following:

```
personList.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(person -> "male".equals(person.getGender())));
```

Printing this will return the following (after implementing `Person#toString`):

```
{false=[Person [Name: Monica, Age: 30, Gender: female], Person [Name: Sophia, Age: 20, Gender: female], Person [Name: Carol, Age: 25, Gender: female]], true=[Person [Name: Adam, Age: 30, Gender: male], Person [Name: John, Age: 32, Gender: male]]}
```

Comment: Piggybacking onto your answer, since `partitioningBy` takes a predicate, the OP could also declare a `Predicate<Person> gender = person -> "male".equals(person.gender());`. Then the stream becomes `collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(gender))`. If only a single gender is of interest, the predicate should be called the target gender (or `groupingBy` should just be used instead).

Comment: @user991710 or use `groupingBy(Person::gender)` instead